# minimizing $\|A\| + \mathrm{trace}(Q(A^TA - 2A))$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Suppose that $Q$ is a symmetric positive definite real matrix. Consider the real-valued function
$$
f_Q(A) = \|A\| + \mathrm{trace}\big(Q(A^TA - 2A)\big).
$$
Is $f_Q$ always minimized over matrices $A$ at a symmetric matrix? Or are there matrices $Q$, positive definite, such that the minimizing $A$ is not symmetric?

Above, $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm of $A$, for instance, given by the largest singular value of $A$. Note that this is a well posed question: by completing the square, we see that
$$
f_Q(A) = \Big\{\|A\| + \mathrm{trace}\Big(Q (I- A)^T(I-A)\Big)\Big\} - \mathrm{trace}(Q).
$$
Hence, one can see that $f_Q(A)$ is naturally bounded below, for each fixed $Q$.

Comment: It's the same if you minimize $\|A\| + \|(I-A)Q^{1/2}\|_F^2$ and you can also suppose $Q$ is diagonal

Comment: Or you can use Schur form and suppose $A$ is upper triangular

Comment: @Exodd but why does this tell us anything about the symmetry of the minimal $A$?

Comment: @DrewBrady Did you do some numerical experiment?

Comment: @RiverLi yeah I tried some random $Q$ PSD and the minimizing $A$ seemed to be symmetric.

Comment: @DrewBrady In your numerical experiment, did you observe that $A =  \alpha I_n$ for some $0\le \alpha < 1$?

Comment: @RiverLi, not that I could see, why?

Comment: @DrewBrady What's your $A$ for $Q = [2, 1; 1, 3]$, for example?